# Loss of Tezos wallet and private code please help me

Tags: tezos-client

테조스 지갑과 프라이빗 코드가 담긴 파일을 기간 만료로 인해 분실했는데 찾을 수 있는 방법을 알려 주세요. The files containing the Tezos wallet and private code have been lost due to period expiration. Please tell me how to find it again.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail about how you created your wallet and why is it expired?

Comment: I got my first wallet from ICO, and I mailed a file containing my wallet and code, but I lost my wallet and private code because the file was left unsaved. 첫 ICO 때 지갑을 발급받았고, 제가 지갑과 코드가 포함된 파일을 메일로 보내었는데, 그 파일을 저장하지 않은 채로 두어 저장 기간 만료로 인하여 코드와 지갑을 분실하였습니다.